# How to find x,y,z such that $\frac{1800}{x}=a$, $\frac{1800}{y}=b$, $\frac{1800}{z}=c$, $\frac{1800}{a+b+c}=d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm really fascinated by how questions and problems are designed in mathematics. So, I was designing a simple word problem, and in the course I fell into this situation:

a,b,c,d are natural numbers.
$a>1$, $b>1$, $c>1$

$a+b+c <1800$

x,y,z are natural numbers.

$x\neq y \neq z $

$x >1$, $y>1$, $z>1$

Find all triplets x,y,z (no need for permutations) so that:

$\dfrac{1800}{x}=a$

$\dfrac{1800}{y}=b$

$\dfrac{1800}{z}=c$

$\dfrac{1800}{a+b+c}=d$

My attempt:

$1800$ has $36$ divisors. But by excluding  $1$ and $1800$, we have $34$ divisors.
Total triplets formed without permutations are $\dfrac{34\cdot33\cdot32}{3\cdot2\cdot1}=5984$

I know by intuition that the solution doesn't probably exceed 8 or 9 triplets, but I'm not able to make any progress.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: As long as $a,b,c$ and $a+b+c$ are divisors of $1800$, you will be able to pick natural numbers $d,x,y,z$ to fulfill the equations. Consider adding a condition such as $a,b,c$ are distinct numbers (makes $a+b+c$ more interesting) or maybe even all coprime (if it works out nicely).

Comment: With a program, I got $371$ triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c,a+b+c$ are all divisors of $1800$ and $a < b < c$.

Comment: $x\neq y \neq z $ is true for $25\neq 30 \neq 25 $ so maybe if you want $x, y, z$ all different you should say that.

Comment: For example, some triplets $(x,y,z)$: $(90, 225, 56)$, $(90, 200, 58)$, $(90, 180, 60)$, $(600, 900, 450)$, etc. I ran my program and I got 7251 results.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: That's really nice. Thank you. I'm still looking for a mathematical approach, if such approach exists.

Comment: @jbuddenh: Thank you for your help. And yes, I want x,y,z all different.

Comment: @ GAVD: Thank you. Apparently, all of you you're telling me there's isn't a mathematical way to solve it.

Comment: I don't know if it helps: Rewrite the equation in form of $$\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z=\frac1d$$

Comment: @Rafiq: There might be a mathematical way, but for me at least writing a program was easier.

Comment: You can condense three conditions $\big((1)\ x \neq y \neq z; (2)\ x > 1, y > 1, z > 1; (3)$ "no need for permutations"$\big)$ into one: $x > y > z > 1$.

Comment: "I know by intuition..." what intuition is that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 324 triples $[x,y,z]$ that make all your conditions true.  I don't know whether $324=18^2$ is a coincidence or not. These were found by a short maple program.  You can see the program and its output here:  http://1drv.ms/1H4yqn2

Comment: I wanted to upvote you, but I haven't that right yet. Thank you so much,jbuddenh